# Determining the highest and lowest prices in a VARIABLE number of bars

Tags: thinkscript

I do not know how to use highestall() or lowestall() here.  I do not know how to use getvalue here that only addresses a single value.  And the highest() function will not work with a variable.  How would I determine the highest value in a known variable range of bars?

All of the above I wrestled with expecting to find the highest value, lowest value, and bar numbers within a variable length series of bars.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This window will not allow me enough characters to paste my code.